# Integration test for Application that interacts with web

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing

How do I write integration test for an application that interacts with website ?
More specifically I have an application that interacts with Flickr website.During the OAuth authorization process flickr website display's the verifier code which the user has to copy and paste into my application. Now how do I automate this process so that I can test the application automatically.I am using swing for GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing automation that depends on external services can be tricky. For something like this, I would advise you to set up a mock service, or some other way of using canned responses.

I've had success doing this a couple of ways:

- Writing an external mock service, using something like [bottle.py](http://bottlepy.org). This has the advantage of requiring little to no modification to your existing codebase, but obviously requires a bit of work to ensure that this external process is managed correctly as part of your test suite, especially if you are running tests in a CI environment.
- Using dependency injection, you can write mock network components, and swap the real network components for your mock components for testing. I recommend this approach, but it will require a bit of modification to your codebase.

Comment: Okay,but what about testing the GUI,especially the part wherein user has to copy and paste in the verifier string into the JTextField ? Is it possible to automate this part ?

Comment: How are you driving the tests in the first place? And my point about mocking the service was to suggest that you would always know the correct code to paste and then you'd be able to set it programmatically via #setText()

Comment: In my test I was directly talking to the flickr server,but as u suggested, now I have my test talk to the mock service, so I know exactly know what to paste with #setText ().